# can you put a shiny progress bar in global.r

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have a data source that needs to be loaded once and so read the data source into the global environment.  I put it in the global environment because the ui.r file needs to access it to take the unique values of some columns to create dropdowns on the ui.

so my global.r has this:

```
############## global.r file
read.csv("mydatasource")
```

My issue is the csv file take about 2 minutes to load so I would like to add a progress bar.

Is it possible to out a `withProgress` in the global.r file?

Also - will the csv be reloaded each time someone comes to the URL?

OR will it only be loaded once which would make the UI faster when someone comes to the URL?

....if it loaded every time is there a way to make it load only once so when a person comes to the URL they don't have to wait?

Comment: If you want the unique values in dropdowns in the UI you can load the data in server and then create the dropdowns with `renderUI`, so you can get `withProgress` to work since it is in server

Comment: Each time someone goes to your URL it initiates a new instance of R, which will have to reload the CSV, so yes the CSV will be reloaded.

Comment: If you don't want to reload the csv each time you could save it as an .Rda instead

Comment: @Carl is there a way in R to do make a csv file an RDA automatically?  Currenlty I have an R script that write the data to a csv file like write.csv(data,mypathofsite) How would I write it to a .RDa file?   and then how would I read the data out of the RDA? currently i am using read.csv() ...I just can't create the RDA manually... Thank you

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html